# Parsing SHOUTcast server information table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, shoutcast

I'm currently trying to parse the html page http://84.19.184.204:8000/played.html using JS.

But it's been hard since I'm new to JS...  The html page contains a table which has the history of last played songs...  This list is what I want to parse.

I use `XMLHttpRequest()` but I can't understand how to parse the elements :(

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Hi @Moto. I hope you are aware that JavaScript running in the browser is probably not a good choice to gather information from another domain due to cross domain restrictions that browsers have in place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well this is for a special browser which doesn't have cross domain restrictions. So that wouldn't be an issue.  I just wish I could get this table into an array... I have tried but I can't get the content values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the static nature of the layout of Shoutcast `played.html` pages, a regular expression would probably be the best choice to extract information. However, see my comment to your question as to why doing this in JavaScript might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Forget that, just get the XML version.  Use this URL:

http://84.19.184.204:8000/admin.cgi?pass=YOURADMINPASSWORD&mode=viewxml

You're looking for the `<SONGHISTORY>` area.

Also, if you do plan on using this on a website, you will need to set up a server-side proxy to access this document.  There are a few hundred ways to do this, so if you aren't sure how, create a new question asking this, with details about what server-side language you are using.  This is how you get around cross-site scripting.