# Get IDv3 tags from shoutcast stream with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, shoutcast

It is possible to access the shoutcast stream with javascript (without flash)?
Need to dynamically update the tags.

Comment: _'yes, its possible'_. But you must clarify: are you trying to do that from a browser? What browser? Is domain with stream the same domain where page that runs javascript is located ?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.  SHOUTcast doesn't use ID3 tags.

SHOUTcast instead uses its own metadata protocol.  You will need to write something server-side that connects to the SHOUTcast server, gets the metadata, and returns it in JSON or something else.  Then, you can use a simple AJAX call to get the data you need.

I've answered this question at least 20 times already on StackOverflow.  See my answers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4069719/362536
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8342918/362536